# Displaying non-ASCII characters in URLs with Safari

Tags: url, utf-8, safari

I am working on a site where I need to generate URLs that contain non-ASCII characters but I am having a problem displaying some characters in the URL correctly in Safari. I want the characters to appear as they are written but Safari displays the %-encoded version instead -  I am using Safari version 6.0.2.

For example, here's a [link](http://www.phraselist.net/items/74/el-d%C3%ADa-despu%C3%A9s) for the Spanish phrase "el día después". If you hover over or click on the link in Chrome, it displays the accented characters 'í' and 'é' correctly in the URL; however, Safari, for some reason, displays the %-encoded version of the character 'í'.

To generate the URL, the text is first encoded as UTF-8 and is then %-encoded, which I believe is the correct way for displaying non-ASCII characters in a URL.

However, if you look at this [link](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2471/how-did-%e5%a4%96%e5%9b%bd%e4%ba%ba-become-%e8%80%81%e5%a4%96) to a post on the Chinese Stack Exchange, Safari *does* display the Chinese characters in the URL correctly.

Any ideas as to why Safari doesn't seem to display accented characters such as 'í' in URLs and how I can get around it?

Comment: Your site is not specifying character encoding, so doing so might help. In PHP: `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");` or in apache config `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Comment: In "día después", it displays "é" as "é" but the "í" as URL encoded for me. Interesting. My spontaneous guess would be that it displays some characters encoded for anti-spoofing reasons. "í" is very easy to mistake for "i", "é" less so. +1 anyway for intriguing question.

Comment: @Esailija I have set the charset parameter to UTF-8 as you suggested but that doesn't seem to have made a difference unfortunately.

Comment: @Simon given that `é` is not urlencoded in safari, it is very likely that deceze's guess is correct.

Comment: Googling around a bit you can find many documents that confirm this behavior for IDNs, but not specifically for other parts of the URL. Since there's only one canonically correct version of the URL, you cannot change the URL and likely there's nothing else you can do to change Safari's behavior (otherwise, what's the point of anti-spoofing?), so I'd just accept this behavior and move on. Technically, displaying anything but percent-encoded characters is wrong to begin with. :)